# Cognos refresh all value prompt

Tags: javascript, cognos

I am trying to use JavaScript in Cognos to reset all the value prompts and textbox prompts to `null`, and refresh the report to show all the data.

I use the following code:

```
<script>
function clearRefresh() {

var oCR = cognos.Report.getReport("_THIS_");

var vDMN = oCR.prompt.getControlByName("Data Model Name");
var vTN = oCR.prompt.getControlByName("Target Name");

vDMN.clearValues();
vTN.clearValues();

oCR.sendRequest (cognos.Report.Action.REPROMPT);

} </script>

<button style="" class="clsPromptButton" onmouseover="this.className = 'clsPromptButtonOver'" onmouseout="this.className = 'clsPromptButton'"
onClick="clearRefresh()">Clear</button>
```

The script appears to just close the report for some reason that I can't figure out.

What is going wrong?

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem with your code. It should do what you expect. You didn't describe the current behavior you are observing. If I know how this code is behaving I can likely figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but I think I am lucky today to figure it out.

Answer (score -2):

**First Code:**

```
<input type="BUTTON" class="clsPromptButton" onClick="fillTextBox()" value="Reset">
```

**Second Code:**

```
<script>
function fillTextBox() {
    var form = getFormWarpRequest();
    var textBox = form._textEditBoxPLP;
    textBox.value = "";

    promptButtonFinish();
}
</script>
```

I have solved the problem using javascripts. Post the code here in case someone search for answer in the future.

The code is composed of two parts, each one with a saparated HTML unit. In the second script, change PLP into your textbox prompt name.

Comment: That's deprecated and unsupported JavaScript. The original code used the JavaScript API which should have worked.